# How to get color of time table on events?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, view, colors

I am creating an events. Also I am creating time tables. Events are created based on time table id. Dynamic event view I have created to show events.

I have created two tables for this events and time table. And loaded events from database.
 Now I have loaded the events from time table witch is enabled. I have set color to time tables. This color I want to show on events with respected time table id.

I tried to load this color using Time table's object.

But I have used for loop so it's showing color of last time table to all events.

How can I set color to event's with respected time table id?

Monday fragment :

```
public class Mon extends Fragment {



    private EventTableHelper mDb;
    private Intent i;
    private ViewGroup dayplanView;
    private int minutesFrom,minutesTo;
    private List<EventData> events;
    private List<View> list;
    private List<TimeTable> tables;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public  boolean editMode;
    private RelativeLayout container;
    private View eventView;
    private TimeTableHelper tableHelper;
    int color;

    private boolean mCheckFragment;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mon, container, false);
        list = new ArrayList<View>();


        dayplanView = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.hoursRelativeLayout);

        showEvents();


        mCheckFragment = true;


        return view;
    }

    private void createEvent(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup dayplanView, int fromMinutes, int toMinutes, String title,String location,final int id,int color,String notification) {

       eventView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_view, dayplanView, false);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) eventView.getLayoutParams();

        container = (RelativeLayout) eventView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) eventView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        list.add(eventView);

        ImageView notify = (ImageView) eventView.findViewById(R.id.notify);


        ((GradientDrawable) eventView.getBackground()).setColor(color);

        tvTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));


        if (tvTitle.getParent() != null)
           ((ViewGroup) tvTitle.getParent()).removeView(tvTitle);

        if(notification == null)
        {
            notify.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else {
            notify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        if(location.equals(""))
        {
            tvTitle.setText("Event : " + title);
        } else {
            tvTitle.setText("Event : " + title + " (At : " + location +")");
        }
        int distance = (toMinutes - fromMinutes);
        layoutParams.topMargin = dpToPixels(fromMinutes + 9);
        layoutParams.height = dpToPixels(distance);

        eventView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        dayplanView.addView(eventView);
        container.addView(tvTitle);



        eventView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddEventActivity.class);
                editMode = true;
                i.putExtra("EditMode", editMode);
                i.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);

            }
        });
    }

    public void showEvents()
    {
        tableHelper = new TimeTableHelper(getActivity());
        tables = tableHelper.getAllTables();

        for (TimeTable table : tables) {

            int tableId = table.getId();
            int status = table.getStatus();
            if(status == 1) {
                color = table.getTableColor();
            }
            mDb = new EventTableHelper(getActivity());
            events = mDb.getTimeTableEvents("Mon", tableId);
        }

        for (EventData eventData : events) {

            int id = eventData.getId();
            String datefrom = eventData.getFromDate();

            if (datefrom != null) {
                String[] times = datefrom.substring(11, 16).split(":");
                minutesFrom = Integer.parseInt(times[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times[1]);
            }
            String title = eventData.getTitle();
            String location = eventData.getLocation();
            String dateTo = eventData.getToDate();

            String notification = eventData.getNotificationTime();

            if (dateTo != null) {
                //times = dateTo.substring(11,16).split(":");
                String[] times1 = dateTo.substring(11, 16).split(":");
                minutesTo = Integer.parseInt(times1[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times1[1]);
            }
            createEvent(inflater, dayplanView, minutesFrom, minutesTo, title, location, id, color, notification);
            id++;
        }


    }

    public void removeView()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            View view = (View)list.get(i);
            dayplanView.removeView(view);
        }
    }

    private int dpToPixels(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {

        super.onResume();

        if(mCheckFragment)
        {
            removeView();
            showEvents();

        }

    }

}
```

EDIT:

```
   public void showEvents()
{
    tableHelper = new TimeTableHelper(getActivity());
    tables = tableHelper.getAllTables();
    int color = 0;
    for (TimeTable table : tables) {

        int tableId = table.getId();
        int status = table.getStatus();

        mDb = new EventTableHelper(getActivity());
        events = mDb.getTimeTableEvents("Mon", tableId);


        for (EventData eventData : events) {

            int id = eventData.getId();
            String datefrom = eventData.getFromDate();

            if (datefrom != null) {
                String[] times = datefrom.substring(11, 16).split(":");
                minutesFrom = Integer.parseInt(times[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times[1]);
            }
            String title = eventData.getTitle();
            String location = eventData.getLocation();
            String dateTo = eventData.getToDate();

            color = table.getTableColor();

            String notification = eventData.getNotificationTime();

            if (dateTo != null) {
                //times = dateTo.substring(11,16).split(":");
                String[] times1 = dateTo.substring(11, 16).split(":");
                minutesTo = Integer.parseInt(times1[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times1[1]);
            }
            createEvent(inflater, dayplanView, minutesFrom, minutesTo, title, location, id, color, notification);
            id++;
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try merging the two for loops together and see if that works..
as well as the color, it also looks like the events are set to the last table when it enters the second for loop.

```
    for(TimeTable table : tables) {
        // code from table for loop
        // ...
        for(EventData eventData : events) {
            // code from event for loop.
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes i thought the same and tried this. But still dose not help. Please check the edited question. @DMO-NZ

Comment: in the last line, why do you increment id? it gets reset to the next eventData's id.. just wondering.. is it important?

Comment: No actually I had tried different method to set an id before. Forgot to remove. Its never used.

Comment: in the original for loop, you checked the status of the table before setting the color;

Comment: Ya i tried to check if there is any difference if i do like that but the result is same.

Comment: I have no clue as to why its not showing the current tables color.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105491/discussion-between-dmo-nz-and-user5881997).